# Is there a way to print data from Firebase Realtime database on a UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uipickerview

I'm developing a business project about creating and mantaining tasks in a Database and I want to display in a Picker all available employees to assign them to the created task in the same function.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        peritoRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            /if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.peritoList.removeAll()

                for peritos in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    let peritoObject = peritos.value as? [String: String]
                    let idPerito = peritoObject?["idPerito"]
                   let nombrePerito = peritoObject?["nombrePerito"]
                 let cargarPerito =  [idPerito, nombrePerito]

                    self.peritoList.append("\(cargarPerito)")
```

I want to know some way to make data in my ref.child("peritos") options on the Picker.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear since `ref.child("peritos")` is not used anywhere in the question so we don't know what it is. Also, it looks like you're taking two values read from Firebase and then creating an array `let cargarPerito =  [idPerito, nombrePerito]` but then that array is cast to a string and then added to a string array? `self.peritoList.append("\(cargarPerito)")`. In other words the array of two values is now a string. Why do that?

Comment: I see the error in the array and I don't know why I did that. I know how to append the values fetched from the Realtime Database to a TableView but in PickerViews the resources are a bit diffuse. I have a list with some employees, organized with an ID and the employee's name. I want the user to select the desired employee and keep that selection to use it after. Thanks for your fast answer Jay, I'm new at the Swift community and I appreciate all help.

Comment: It's still very unclear what you are asking. As mentioned previously `ref.child("peritos")` is not used anywhere in the question so we don't know what that is. You say you know how to read data from Firebase and populate a dataSource array so what's the specific issue? Can you show the code you are having difficulty with? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Clarify and we'll take a look!